# How to remember the Electromagnetic Spectrum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, education, mnemonic

This may sound off-topic but I am in a severe need of remembering the following shown Electromagnetic Spectrum along with the frequencies and wavelengths. So far I have looked at several mnemonics but they only help me to remember the order which I now know but I could find no way to remember it along with frequencies and wavelengths.

[image]

I am an Intermediate (class 12) student and in my exams I will be given a frequency(or wavelength) and I will have to tell to what part of the EM spectrum does it belong. I can manage the applications but not the frequency and wavelengths. Please Help me in the stand.

Cheers!:)

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole Electromagnetic Spectrum"? It has no upper limit in frequency and no upper limit in wavelength... Are you thinking of a certain sequence of common names of regions? Like "radio waves"? Why don't you list the names you are trying to remember and then we can help you come up with a mnemonic... or better yet just come up with your own...

Comment: @hft, I have edited the question have a look please.

Comment: Note also that the ranges don't have precise borders, they are instead just orders of magnitude or, in some cases, just conventions.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher actually wants you to remember the specific frequency and wavelength ranges... because that sounds like completely unnecessary and irrelevant torture to me.

Comment: Unnecessary to remember these.
you can simply google or open the book when you need and also in most questions you are already provided the wavelenght.

Comment: @Paul: It's also unnecessary to remember the periodic table. But you do see a lot of students memorizing that too.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good grasp on the relative scales of other things in physics, you may be able to relate the wavelengths to those.  Otherwise, your best bet is just to memorize the wavelengths (or frequencies).  Since $f = \frac{c}{\lambda}$ for light, you'll be able to figure out the frequencies if you know the wavelengths.

Here are some things I use to help me remember.  These will only be useful to you if you're familiar with the other concepts.  Note, although your textbook uses the term "electron waves" it is not common parlance in physics.  We refer to these waves simply as another band of radio waves.

- Radio: The *largest* wavelengths.  Car antennas pick up radio waves, so $\lambda_{radio}$ includes $1m$ (the length of an antenna) and anything larger. Also, radio stations always give their frequencies in $MHz$, which is $10^6 Hz$.
- Microwave: Like high-frequency radio waves.  Microwave ovens must fit several wavelengths inside the body, which is tens of centimetres wide, so $\lambda_{microwave} \sim 1cm$.  Microwaves can't escape the mesh on the front of a microwave oven, so also $\lambda_{microwave} > 1 mm$.
- Infrared: No idea, between microwave and visible.
- Visible: You have to use these numbers all the time in physics.  Visible light has wavelengths between $400 nm$ and $700 nm$, or a few $10^{-7}m$.
- UV: Between visible and X-Ray.
- X-Ray: Can see your bones! Has an energy measured in $keV$, which via $E=hf$ gives frequencies of $10^{18}Hz$.
- Gamma Rays: Crazy high energy!  Nuclear reactions release gamma rays, as does electron pair annihilation.  An electron has a rest-mass of energy of $511 keV$, so gamma rays must have the same energy, which gives you a frequency of $10^{20}Hz$, or anything higher.

To reiterate, these are just the associations I use to keep the numbers straight.   They're only useful because through experience I've ended up memorizing things like electrons weighing $511 keV$.  If you also know this fact, that's awesome! You can use it to remember the frequency of gamma rays. If you don't, then don't worry, to study you should just memorize the frequency of gamma rays.

Comment: In his book "radio wave" are not the longest, they consider radiation from household electronic devices at 60Hz... I'll edit it for ya. Fixed the MHz fiasco mentioned above as well.

Comment: I also want to edit out a few of those exclamation points... but I guess I'll leave them in...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit.  That was indeed a fiasco with the MHz, a good lesson in why proof reading is essential.

Comment: @hft: Radio waves extend down to 60Hz and considerably lower. I have never heard of "electron waves" - or at least not as an expression to describe long wavelength EM.

Comment: @JohnRennie: The OP's study guide included "electron" waves. It's not a term I like, but his teacher seems to think otherwise.

Comment: @GeoffRyan: right, but this is the Physics SE and we expect answers here to be accurate, not to follow the eccentricities of some textbook.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Fair enough!  I added a note about this in the answer.

Comment: The textbook obviously is referring to the oscillation of electrons in the copper wiring in household power systems when it says "electron waves". Yeah, this is a stupid term that I have also never heard before, but the kid is asking for a mnemonic to help him pass his test... The term is not *wrong* per se, it is just silly/strange. But then again the whole damn idea of memorizing all that crap is silly/strange.

Comment: X-ray can be used to see things at the atomic level, hence the wavelength has the order of magnitude of $1 Å = 0.1$ nm.